# Is there any efficient way to save variables with changing file names sequentially in python?

Tags: python, list, variables

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io

ori[0] = io.imread('/Dataset/A01/0000.tif')
...
ori[100] = io.imread('/Dataset/A01/0099.tif')
```

I want to save the files(0000 ~ 0099.tif) into list.
But, if I write the code like above, it needs about 100 line just for saving variables.
Is there any efficient way to do the same things?
Specifically, changing from 0000 to 0099 automatically is the key to solve this. But, I have no idea. Could you please give me some tips for this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of for-loops? This is an obvious use case for one. You can use zfill() method of string to fill file names with leading zeros.

```
for i in range(100):
    filename = str(i).zfill(4)
    ori[i] = io.imread(f'/Dataset/A01/{filename}.tif')
```

Edit: As comment by chepner suggested, you can use f-strings to add leading zeros.

```
for i in range(100):
    ori[i] = io.imread(f'/Dataset/A01/{i:04d}.tif')
```

Comment: f-strings can handle the formatting done by `zfill`.

Answer (score 3):

Try with loop over `range`. And maintain a temp variable for file path increment.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io

file = '/Dataset/A01/00{}.tif'
for i in range(100):
    file_inc = str(i).zfill(2)
    ori[i] = io.imread(file.format(file_inc))
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple list comprehension will do.

```
ori = [io.imread(f'/Dataset/A01/{i:04}.tif') for i in range(100)]
```